# Calling system config value

Tags: magento2

I am trying to get my system config values and so far compared to M1 it's been very frustrating.
I am following this [tutorial](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html).

Everything works fine, but as soon as I want to call the values with:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('helloworld/general/enable', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

I get a

```
Notice: Undefined property:Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Test\Interceptor::$scopeConfig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define construct function for pass the object manager as DI.

Define below code in your file in construct function

```
protected $_scopeConfig;
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
```

Now call config value with below code

```
$value = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('helloworld/general/enable', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

run command php bin/magento setup:di:compile.

it should work now.

Comment: Do you know how to call the value of a specific sore view?